# Angular 4 draggable become image while dragging

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, safari, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing a drag and drop function using Angular 4, ngx-drag-drop. When I ran the code on chrome, the draggable item become a static image (i can tell from it's background. But in Safari it works fine (remain as a div). Is there anything wrong with chrome? Or it's just ngx-drag-drop is not compatible with chrome. 
This is how it looks like on Chrome:
[image]

And this is on Safari:
[image]
Below are the code:

```
<div class="device" [dndDraggable]="draggable.data"
                 [dndEffectAllowed]="draggable.effectAllowed"
                 [dndDisableIf]="draggable.disable"
                 (dndStart)="onDragStart($event)"
                 (dndCopied)="onDraggableCopied($event)"
                 (dndLinked)="onDraggableLinked($event)"
                 (dndMoved)="onDraggableMoved($event)"
                 (dndCanceled)="onDragCanceled($event)"
                 (dndEnd)="onDragEnd($event)">
                        <div class="part1"></div>
                        <div class="part2"></div>
                        <div class="part3"></div>
                 </div>
<section class="phone" dndDropzone
                     (dndDragover)="onDragover($event)"
                     (dndDrop)="onDrop($event)"
                     >
                <div class="top">
                </div>
            </section>
```

On ts file:

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

draggable = {
    // note that data is handled with JSON.stringify/JSON.parse
    // only set simple data or POJO's as methods will be lost 
    data: "myDragData",
    effectAllowed: "copyMove",
    dropEffect: "move",
    disable: false,
    handle: false
  };
...
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me? Really appreciate it!

Comment: In fact I'm not sure if the div has become an image. But I'm sure that even if I set the background of the div to transparent, it still shows the blue grid background when I drag the div.